# Simple HTML DOM get dynamic content loaded with JS

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, simple-html-dom, dynamic-content

I'm trying to get a dynamically loaded content from a web page. Specifically the options loaded to a select. So if I do:

```
$options = $html->find('select[class=theSelectClass]')[0]->find('option');
foreach($options as $option){
     echo $option->text().'<br>';
}
```

This works as expected and my output is:

```
Select an option
```

Why? Because the other options are loaded with JS after the page loads. So my question is how can I get this dynamically loaded options inside the select?

This is my attempt using JS Ajax and another PHP page:

in my php that includes the simple_html_dom:

```
$html->load_file($base);
$var = '<script>

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/crawler/ajax.php?param=HelloWorld", true);
    xhttp.send();

</script>';
$e = $html->find("body", 0);
$e->outertext = $e->makeup() . $e->innertext . $var . '</body>';
```

and my ajax.php file:

```
file_put_contents ( 'ajax.txt' , $_GET['param']);
```

I was trying to see if I could send an Ajax call from the html loaded file, but I feel far from being able to do it. So how can I make this happen?

Thank you

Comment: `but I feel far from being able to do it.`  Some people would frown at me for saying this, but you could use jQuery,. there is a simple .get() function for loading html dynamically into an element.

Comment: Are you saying replacing XMLHttpRequest for a jQuery get() will fix it? If that is correct I really don't see how that can help since get function implements a XMLHttpRequest object behind anyways.

Comment: You can certainly keep using XMLHttpRequest, the point of the jQuery is that it's battle tested, and with you saying `but I feel far...`, but if you feel fine doing pure javascript, then fair do's.  What your asking for is certainly doable.  You might find you have not waited for DOM ready, again you could do this without jQuery, but simple `$(function ())` would get the DOM ready bit out the way too.

Comment: My problem is that since it's a generated code, I don't know where are the options loaded

Comment: And you could try it first with jQuery, and then later remove once you know it's working etc.  jQuery has it's uses, and one great use is for quickly mocking up an idea.  Go pure javascript, or go a battle tested lib, the choice is yours. Oh, That sounds like some game show :)

Comment: ok i'll give it a try and come back

Comment: Surely your select has an id or similar, and then you could do  `$('#someid').get(theurl);`

Comment: I think Keith is confusing you. An ajax request is the same as any other request. Just get it with curl and parse the output.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier for you to first use a headless browser to render the page then pass that to simple html dom. You could do this with CasperJS/PhantomJS or another tool that renders the page with javascript.

`

```
require("vendor/autoload.php");
use Sunra\PhpSimple\HtmlDomParser;
use Browser\Casper;
$casper = new Casper();
// forward options to phantomJS
// for example to ignore ssl errors
$casper->setOptions(array(
    'ignore-ssl-errors' => 'yes'
));
$casper->start('https://www.reddit.com');
$casper->wait(5000);
$output = $casper->getOutput();
$casper->run();
$html = $casper->getHtml();
$dom = HtmlDomParser::str_get_html( $html );
$elems = $dom->find("a");
foreach($elems as $e){
    print_r($e->href);
}
```

?>`

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. This is advise. It should be a comment.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little further? How can I use CasperJS to achieve this? An example or something would be awesome :)

Comment: Take a look at these two api sections
https://github.com/alwex/php-casperjs

http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#gethtml

The flow would be get webpage -> saveHTML to file or variable then load in simplehtmldom to parse

Comment: Mmm don't see how that can help. If I get the souce code of the page in a browser the options are not loaded. Only if I use the inspect Chrome tool I can see them loaded.

Comment: PhantomJS renders the dom for you. 

https://gist.github.com/alanmbarr/40f900ad9261b80a5b027761c389ff8a

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising, Casper dosen't seem to find PhantomJS. Since http://phantomjs.org/download.html only downloads a .exe (on windows) how can I make Casper find Phantom?

Comment: @alanmbarr Sorry to bother you but I can't run the example here https://github.com/alwex/php-casperjs, neither I can your exaple code. I always get an error saying Casper.php can't find casperJS. Like this: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Can not find CasperJS.' in 'Casper.php' please help me :)

Comment: yeah its annoying in linux type 
`which casperjs`

whatever you get put 
`sudo ln -sf REPLACE_THIS /usr/local/bin/casperjs`

The library assumes the casperjs binary is located or symlinked to this location

Comment: If you are on windows you might need to edit the casper.php file from the library where your casperjs is located on windows. Otherwise use a docker image for this. https://ide.c9.io/alanmbarr/phpcasper I set it up in cloud9 pretty quickly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125210/discussion-between-alanmbarr-and-alejandro).